# Taylor Series and Continued Fractions

Tags: calculus, continued-fractions

I was looking into applications of continued fractions in Physics, I found that it is possible to find a rational estimate of an irrational function; which I guess can be used for creating bode plots and any calculations that depend on a transfer function to be rational.

But how is it possible to write a Taylor series expansion as a continued fraction?
Say we have a functions,

$$H(s) = \frac{1}{cosh(\sqrt(s))}$$

and we want to write it as a Polynomial/Polynomial, how can we do that using continued fraction of Taylor series?

And secondary question, is there a reason to use continued fractions over just using the Taylor series? would you get a better estimate maybe?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is the standard Euler continued fraction

Comment: If you want a rational approximation that’s more suitable than a Taylor expansion, Padé approximants are a thing